# Inputting Parameters in LISP without quote operator (Property List/Semantic Network/Basic Functions)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, property-list

It's been a little while since I've used LISP. I'm using it right now to make a property list to represent a semantic network. I can't seem to figure out this basic issue though and it's blocking all progress for now.

The kind of input we are expecting is as follows:

```
     (FACT (IS-A SEAT1 SEAT))
     (FACT (IS-A L1 LEG))
     (FACT (IS-A L2 LEG))
     (FACT (IS-A L3 LEG))
```

Just take the first one as an example. Firstly, I'm getting a little stumped on how to call a function within another like that. My initial idea was to make a function called fact and use a cond statement to see whether it was using "is-a" or "connected" (the other possibility), but with that extra parenthesis there before "is-a" or "connected", I'm not sure how I'd approach that.

In an effort to at least see if I'm getting the basic idea down, I decided to skip straight to the "is-a" part. This should basically be creating the object.

```
    (defun is-a (name type)
        (setf (get type 'name) name)
    )
```

Ideally this would work, but in order to actually call the function, you need to put the quote operator in front of the parameters since they aren't variables. So the call would look like:

```
    (is-a 'seat1 'seat)
```

Without those quotes, CLISP complains that the variable has no value. So how would I go about making something that could read in the input exactly as shown above, without the quote?

Comment: In your case I would worry about the notation last. First get the algorithmic part working.

Answer (score 1):

Your property lists are not meant to be evaluated. They're meant to be `read` in and processed. Your processing function can then pick out symbols like `fact` and `is-a` and `connected` and handle them appropriately.

But, since you're not evaluating them, you should not define procedures (or macros!) for `fact`, `is-a`, or `connected`.

Comment: So are you suggesting something more along the lines of reading in each line and then parsing through to see what needs to be done with it?

The thing that kind of throws me off is how the queries are going to be handled. My first inclination is to simply look through using the given values with the query to see if that exists.

`code`
(query value (is-a value seat))
`code`
Should return: seat1

Comment: You'd read in a form (rather than a line) at a time, but the rough idea is correct.

Comment: I don't recall seeing anything about forms in my previous course. I'll have to go look into that now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: "Your property lists are not meant to be evaluated. They're meant to be read in and processed."  I agree, except that these don't really seem to be property lists so much as logical formulae.  It might actually be appropriate in this case to define a **fact** *macro* that asserts the formulae within (or cause it to be otherwise interpreted as appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities here. If you're trying directly evaluate those lines and you want `(FACT (IS-A SEAT1 SEAT))` to define a variable called `seat1` of type `seat`, you could do it like this:

```
(defvar input '(FACT (IS-A SEAT1 SEAT)))

(defmacro fact (&body expr)
  `(progn . ,expr))

(defmacro is-a (name type)
  `(defparameter ,name (make-instance ',type)))

(defclass seat () ())

(eval input)
```

Alternately, you could make `seat1` be a key in a hash table by defining `is-a` like this:

```
(defvar *objects* (make-hash-table))

(defmacro is-a (name type)
  `(setf (gethash ',name *objects*) (make-instance ',type)))

(defclass seat () ())

(eval input)
```

There's `destructuring-bind`:

```
(defvar input '(FACT (IS-A SEAT1 SEAT)))

(destructuring-bind (type (operator operand-1 operand-2)) input
  (format t "It is a ~a that ~a ~a ~a~%" type operand-1 operator operand-2))
```

Output:

```
It is a FACT that SEAT1 IS-A SEAT
```

The LOOP macro can also destructure:

```
(loop for (type (operator operand-1 operand-2)) in list-of-inputs
   do
     (format t "It is a ~a that ~a ~a ~a~%" type operand-1 operator operand-2))
```